# Excel - if condition many arguments

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

excel says many arguments for this function

```
=IF(OR(AND(F2=6,C2=0,O2>=19.2),TRUE),IF(AND(F2=7,C2=0,O2>=20.2),TRUE),IF(AND(F2=8,C2=0,O2>=21.2),TRUE),IF(AND(F2=9,C2=0,O2>=22.4),TRUE))
```

Comment: The nested `OR()` does not make sense since you check for the `AND()` statements or `TRUE`. But what needs to be true? Maybe you meant something like `=OR(AND(F2=6,C2=0,O2>=19.2),AND(F2=7,C2=0,O2>=20.2),AND(F2=8,C2=0,O2>=21.2),AND(F2=9,C2=0,O2>=22.4))` however I'm just guessing here.

Comment: i removed the or so it will be =IF(AND(F2=6,C2=0,O2>=19.2),TRUE),IF(AND(F2=7,C2=0,O2>=20.2),TRUE),IF(AND(F2=8,C2=0,O2>=21.2),TRUE),IF(AND(F2=9,C2=0,O2>=22.4),TRUE)

Comment: the true because the F2=6 might be 7 or anything else because F2 is age column

Comment: It looks like you just want a TRUE/FALSE result, so you don't need IF at all: `=OR(AND(F2=6,C2=0,O2>=19.2),AND(F2=7,C2=0,O2>=20.2),AND(F2=8,C2=0,O2>=21.2),AND(F2=9,C2=0,O2>=22.4))`